# .NET MAUI App Crashes when working on ObservableRangCollection: Watchdog Termination

Tags: maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI App which is running without problems in iOS Emulator. I also did a Release Deployment on my iPhone 14 Pro Max and played around with the App.

I was surprised the App closed at some point from one second to the other. Well, the first time is just suprising, but when it happened a second time I was a bit cautious what actions I did to figure out if there is a problem in my code.

Well, could not figure out critical points and the actions I did were just were in the context of adding or manipulating items in my ObservableRangeCollections. I use a couple of them in my ViewModels and at least one of the Crashes was in a View in which I just add new items to the Database (EF Core) and to the ObservableRangeCollection which is bound to a CollectionView to display all items.

The other View that caused a crash at a certain point was when I select items and just manipulate a Flag which is causing updates on another ObservableRangeCollection regarding this flag to display or hide elements in the View.

After a while, I added try-catch-Blocks to see if there is an Exception in these routines, but nothing - the App was just gone shut down. Then, I installed **Sentry** to see if I can get some more information out of it. It did not report every crash of the App, but one point was interesting:

`WatchdogTermination: The OS watchdog terminated your app, possibly because it overused RAM.`

The breadcrumbs showed several items

```
WatchdogTermination: The OS watchdog terminated your app, possibly because it overused RAM.

ui.rendering
BoxView.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
Label.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
BoxView.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
Label.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
BoxView.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
Label.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
BoxView.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
Label.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
BoxView.SizeChanged

ui.rendering
Label.SizeChanged

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'Max' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'IsValid' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Bound'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'Min' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'StudentItem' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'

ui.rendering
VerticalStackLayout.SizeChanged
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'IsValid' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Bound'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'Max' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'IsValid' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Bound'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'Min' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'StudentItem' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'StudentItem' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'MyApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomLabel.CultureBasedNumberLabel.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'StudentItem' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'MyApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomLabel.CultureBasedNumberLabel.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'StudentItem' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'MyApp.Pages.Views.Controls.CustomLabel.CultureBasedNumberLabel.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'OptimalAmount' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'IsValid' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Bound'

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
'Max' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CalculateViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Entry.Text'
```

**The information about the Memory usage was as follows**:

[image]

I really don't know what to say here anymore and what the problem might be. But, interestingly, it did not find some properties in between that are part of the ObservableRangeCollection and should be there.

The other thing with crashing is still, why when there are things added to ObservableRangeCollections which is the purpose of collections.

Are there any hints or tipps or anything I can do to prevent this?

**==== Update 1: trying to get the dotnet-trace ====**

Before I started the Debug-Build of my App with iOS Simulator, I tried to set the `DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts` variable as follows in the PowerShell command prompt in VS. I also tried with absolute path to my App-Folder which also did not work:

```cs
PM> DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts="~/my-dev-port,suspend" ./bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/MyApp.app
DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=~/my-dev-port,suspend : The term 'DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=~/my-dev-port,suspend' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts="~/my-dev-port,suspend" ./bin/Debug/net7.0-ios ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DOTNET_Diagnost...ev-port,suspend:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PM> $DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts="~/my-dev-port,suspend" ./bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/MyApp.app
At line:1 char:49
+ ... rt,suspend" ./bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/MyApp ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token './bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/MyApp.app' in expression or statement.
PM>
```

I am pretty sure that there is a Memory-Leak problem, but the Wiki-Page from the Comment did not help me to identify what I should change. I am using a Grid in XAML with ColumnDefinitions as mentioned in the Wiki, but not in Code-Behind but in XAML.

Also one of my ViewModels needs to be static and is used from different Views. But the Objects in the ViewModel, such as ObservableRangeCollections are also kept small by just filling them with the content needed using Clear() and then filling them with the corresponding data needed. So, currently really no clue what to do.

In a BottomSheet I display, I have ToogleButtons with the elements selected. When I select 2-3 of them and close, I manage them internally and set the states to true/false correspondingly. In another ObservableRangeCollection I just select the elements that are selected and based on that a CollectionView with a DataTemplate is displaying just the selected ones from the second ObservableRangeCollection. The first one is just to Display all elements in the BottomSheet and the second one is to display the selected elements.

When I open and close the BottomSheet and do not select or unselect elements just open/close a couple of times, memory consumption is growing for an unknown reason.

When starting the App again and in another test do not select anything, just open and close the BottomSheet, memory consumption is not growing and stays the same.

Interestingly, same code is executed behind the scenes, but nothing grows. Well, the selected elements are not in the second list. But, as the second list is filled dynamically just with the selected elements and the ObservableRangeCollection is Cleared with Clear() before adding new elements this is strange.

**==== Update 2: Can't do the mlaunch step ====**

I was following the description in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Profiling:

[image]

First, I executed the `dotnet-dsrouter` command. What I was wondering about in the description was that it should listen to the localhost (127.0.0.1). But, I am working on Windows and I am not sure if the Simulator-Code is actually executed on my Mac as the Mac is providing the Simulator. But anyway, when I use the IP-Address of my Mac it does not work, so I kept it with the address.

I am working in VS and was starting a PowerShell to execute the command:

1. dotnet-dsrouter client-server -ipcc ~/my-sim-port -tcps 127.0.0.1:9000

[image]

At least this command is waiting for something to connect

2. Step 2 of the description is actually a bit of a problem for me as I don't know where I can enter it as PowerShell within my VS instance does not know about "mlaunch". Anyway, when I right-click my .NET MAUI project and got to iOS > Run Options, I can see a Textfield "Extra mlaunch arguments" and provided the following:

```
--launchsim bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/*/*.app --device :v2:udid=C19459C0-F4ED-4E8C-BE1E-A897AF774744 --wait-for-exit --argument --connection-mode --argument none '--setenv:DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=127.0.0.1:9000,suspend''
```

C19459C0-F4ED-4E8C-BE1E-A897AF774744 is the device ID for my iPhone 14 Pro Max (C19459C0-F4ED-4E8C-BE1E-A897AF774744) determined on my Mac via `xcrun simctl list devices`

I also tried with:

```
--launchsim bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/*/*.app --device :v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-14-Pro-Max --wait-for-exit --argument --connection-mode --argument none '--setenv:DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=127.0.0.1:9000,suspend'
```

[image]

The App started in iOS Simulator, but no output in the PowerShell console.

Another approach was to look for mlaunch in my Windows directories and make an alias to it then call the command and all other options above:

```
Set-Alias -Name mlaunch -Value 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.4.60\tools\lib\mlaunch\mlaunch.app\Contents\MonoBundle\mlaunch.exe'
```

```
mlaunch --launchsim bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/*/*.app --device :v2:udid=C19459C0-F4ED-4E8C-BE1E-A897AF774744 --wait-for-exit --argument --connection-mode --argument none '--setenv:DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=127.0.0.1:9000,suspend'
```

Exception:

```
error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/new
System.TypeInitializationException: Der Typeninitialisierer für "AppKit.NSApplication" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: Der Typeninitialisierer für "ObjCRuntime.Selector" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
   bei ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle(String name)
   bei ObjCRuntime.Selector..cctor() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/ObjCRuntime/Selector.mac.cs:Zeile 32.
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle(String name)
   bei AppKit.NSApplication..cctor() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/mac/mobile/AppKit/NSApplication.g.cs:Zeile 53.
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei AppKit.NSApplication.Init()
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.Main(String[] args) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:Zeile 121.

Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.exit(Int32 exitcode)
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.Exit(Int32 exitCode) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:Zeile 111.
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.<>c.<Main>b__63_1(Int32 exitCode) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:Zeile 126.
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.ErrorHelper.Exit(Int32 exitCode) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/ErrorHelper.cs:Zeile 92.
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.ErrorHelper.Show(Exception e) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/ErrorHelper.cs:Zeile 86.
   bei Xamarin.Launcher.Driver.Main(String[] args) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/4/s/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Launcher/Main.cs:Zeile 127.
```

3. Step 3 mentions to wait until we see the output but I could never see that:

```
The runtime has been configured to pause during startup and is awaiting a Diagnostics IPC ResumeStartup command from a Diagnostic Port
```

As it never was shown, I think there is anything wrong

4. The next command was executed at least, but obviously did not dump any file. At least, I could not see it. Where would I expect it to be?

```
dotnet-trace collect --diagnostic-port ~/my-sim-port --format speedscope
```

```
dotnet-trace collect --diagnostic-port ~/my-sim-port --format speedscope
No profile or providers specified, defaulting to trace profile 'cpu-sampling'

Provider Name                           Keywords            Level               Enabled By
Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler     0x0000F00000000000  Informational(4)    --profile
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime         0x00000014C14FCCBD  Informational(4)    --profile

Waiting for connection on ~/my-sim-port
Start an application with the following environment variable: DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=~/my-sim-port
```

I also tried to connect to a real device as you propsed. But there I already could not execute the following command and got a failure:

```
dotnet-dsrouter server-client -ipcs ~/my-dev-port -tcpc 127.0.0.1:9001 --forward-port iOS
```

**Failure**:

```
info: dotnet-dsrouter-15156[0]
      Starting dotnet-dsrouter using pid=15156
info: dotnet-dsrouter-15156[0]
      Starting IPC server (~/my-dev-port) <--> TCP client (127.0.0.1:9001) router.
fail: dotnet-dsrouter-15156[0]
      Failed running subscribe loop: Unable to load DLL '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation' or one of its dependencies: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (0x8007007E). Disabling detection of devices connected over USB.
```

Comment: It seems to be related to memory leak, you can refer to the official wiki: [Memory Leaks](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Memory-Leaks).

Comment: I have a Bottom Sheet control and could figure out that when I open and close it for about 10 times without changing anything the App closes. I did an output of the Memory Consumption of GC and it is just about 34 MB when it does that and in Debug Mode nothing happens. Unfortunately, what did not work so far was, working with the Diagnostic Tools in VS just did not display anything. Apart from that, I can’t really identify the do’s and don’ts in this Wiki so that Memory Leaks don’t come up. Maybe also just the changes of my ItemSources by assigning a new instance of my ObservableRangeCollectio

Comment: Have you used `dotnet-trace` tool to monitor([here of the wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5McO3.png)) ?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but obviously I am too dumb to set that up. I wanted to run my App as a Debug-Build and then do the dotnet-trace as described from VS 2022 on Windows running the iOS-Version. I tried setting the environment Variable DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts as in the example, but got the outputs from the Update of my question. What I am also wondering about it that in VS the Diagnostic Tools don't show anything when I run my App. Is this normal when compiling the App with .NET 7? They just wrote about not fully supported. But this for me is like not supported at all?

Comment: *They just wrote about not fully supported. But this for me is like not supported at all?* Yes, there is this possibility about it. In addition, have you tried to monitor on [real device](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Profiling#device)?

Comment: This I haven’t tried so far, but can try today. I was fixed trying to get the other commands running and trying to figure out why my VS Diagnostic Tool Window is empty and not showing anything. Is this due to a possible unsupported .NET 7 used for my App or am I doing something wrong? The CLI options described in the Wiki also did not work. Probably I am doing something wrong then  Just to make sure the CLI commands from the Wiki and the link „real device“ you shared are executed on my Windows PC where VS is running and executing my iOS 16.2 Simulator?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT - I tried different things without success which I described in **Update 2** of my question. Do you have any ideas or explanation how you do it?